# PostgreSQL/PostGIS cast geometry column of joined table to varchar while creating another table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry

A simple `SELECT` on a table with a `geometry` column works, but creating a table from this query automatically cast the column to `varchar`.

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE importe AS
SELECT fid, id, structure_, validite, visible, nom, commentair, depart, arrivee, confort, "source", "enjeu_d'en",
usages, reseaux, "date_d'ins", date_de_mo, communes, secteurs, zonage_reg, longueur_2, longueur_3, denivele_p,
denivele_n, altitude_m, altitude_1, pente, layer, "path", e.geom
FROM rlesi_nord r
LEFT JOIN ma_topo.edge_data e ON (r.topo).id = e.edge_id;
```

`ma_topo` is my topology schema, `edge_data` is the table from which I get the geom for `importe` rows.

I tried to explicitly cast it to `geometry` but it doesn't change anything:

```
e.geom::geometry
```

There isn't a problem when I create a table with a geom column which belongs to the table of the `FROM` clause (and not of the `JOIN` like my initial query).